# MongoDB C# 2.1.0 Driver - Custom method support in Linq expression

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

Is it possible to define a FilterDefinition for a method on a POCO? For example, given the following objects:

```
public class Poco {

    // Other members

    public CustomGeometry Location { get; set; }
}

public class CustomGeometry {

    public bool Near(double lat, double lon){
        // Implementation
    }

}
```

Assuming the CustomGeometry serialization is being handled correctly, is there a way to translate the following query:

```
pocoCollection.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.Location.Near(45.0, -85.0));
```

Into something that could be built with the Builder helper class:

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Near("Location", 45.0, -85.0);
```

I've looked through the documentation and the code without any luck. I want to make sure I'm not missing something before attempting to add the functionality myself.